# Mongodb update() vs. findAndModify() performance

Tags: javascript, mongodb, performance, mongoose, database

For a **constantly growing** document, I have the choice of using either `update()` or `findAndModify()` to **insert new elements in an array field**. However, `findAndModify()` will generate cleaner code in my specific application. But I can achieve the same functionality using `update()`, just more messy.

I'm just wondering how much is the performance gain by using `update()` instead of `findAndModify()`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The doc has [some comparison between both functions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#comparisons-with-the-update-method). Usually the key points to make your decision are _"Does the client need to read the document or only to modify it ?"_ and _"Does the client need to specify some order to update one specific document when there are multiple matches ?"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a quick test using the mongo shell.  For this document:

```
{
   "c" : 50,
   "growingArray" : [ 0 ]
}
```

I ran two tests:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
{
    db.testids.update( { "c" : 50 }, { $addToSet : { "growingArray" : i } } );
}
```

Took a total of **40.926s** on my mid-range laptop.

The `findAndModify()` version:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
{
    db.testids.findAndModify({ query: { "c" : 50 }, update : { $addToSet : { "growingArray" : i } } } );
}
```

took **42.445** seconds.   I averaged five runs of each.

Take from it what you will.  The knee-jerk conclusion is that you have about a 3% to 4% overhead with `findAndModify()` in my particular environment with nothing else going on.  Keep in mind though that findAndModify() obtains write locks so you could have a much greater impact on performance of your application overall.

Comment: Very persuading theory and test result, I think if you are saving some critical data, it is worth to spend a little more time with `findAndModify()` .