# MongoDB - .update() vs .findAndModify() error

Tags: mongodb

The following is more of a question out of curiosity.

I'm currently running a script that updates each user in my database by pushing an ObjectID reference to into an array within the user schema.

From my understanding, there is [little difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274569/mongodb-update-vs-findandmodify-performace) between the `.update` and `.findAndModify` commands in MongoDB. **However**, I receive an error when I use `.findAndModify` whereas `.update` works perfectly well.

Here's my script:

```
var panos = db.panos.find();
var total = 0;
while(panos.hasNext()) {
    var pano = panos.next();
    var author = db.users.findOne({ _id: pano._id});

    /* here I use the .update command */
    db.users.update(
        { _id: ObjectId(pano.author) },
        { $addToSet: { panos: pano._id }}
    );

    total++;
    print('total looked at:', total)
}
```

And the users are updated as expected. When I replace `.users()` with `.findAndModify()`, the following error logs in the console:

```
Error: findAndModifyFailed failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no such command: _id",
    "code" : 59,
    "bad cmd" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5616dd0a35ea7932106b7c57"),
        "findandmodify" : "users"
    }
}
```

It looks like the `_id` query is giving a problem, but I can't wrap my head around why. I've tried replacing `ObjectId(pano.author)` with just `pano.author` but to no avail.

**TL;DR: .update works where .findAndModify doesn't**

Comment: Atomicity is a more relevant difference between them two. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778493/whats-the-difference-between-findandmodify-and-update-in-mongodb?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shell, [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) takes a single parameter object rather than separate parameters like `update`, so you need to call it as:

```
db.users.findAndModify({
    query: { _id: ObjectId(pano.author) },
    update: { $addToSet: { panos: pano._id }}
});
```